# How to extract only paragraphs from pdf using python or java?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, pypdf, pdfminer

We could able to extract entire text from pdf using pypdf2 and pdfbox but not able to fetch only paragraphs.

Comment: What is a paragraph? Well, ok, I have an idea what a paragraph is when I see it, but in a PDF there doesn't need to be a structure marking a paragraph as such. Or do you happen to only deal with tagged PDFs marking paragraphs?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the text and split by `\n\n`.

If you want to extract text from a specific region, use a visitor function: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html#using-a-visitor